# Is Byte Really The Minimum Addressable Unit?

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer, standards, memory-model

Section 3.6 of C11 standard defines "byte" as "addressable unit of data storage ... to hold ... character".

Section 1.7 of C++11 standard defines "byte" as "the fundamental storage unit in the C++ memory model ... to contain ... character".

Both definitions does not say that "byte" is the minimum addressable unit. Is this because standards intentionally want to abstract from a specific machine ? Can you provide a real example of machine where C/C++ compiler were decided to have "byte" longer/shorter than the minimum addressable unit ?

Comment: One of my favorite unusual architectures is the [HP Saturn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_Saturn).  It is a 4-bit CPU and the machine can address nibbles.  There is [a gcc port](http://hp48xgcc.sourceforge.net/hp48xgcc.htm) for which `char` is 8 bits.  Is that the sort of thing you're looking for?

Comment: I think you should not modify your quotes that much. The [relevant C++11 section](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/intro.memory#1) says: "*The fundamental storage unit in the C++ memory model is the byte.*" This is one full sentence without qualification. Then it adds "*A byte is at least large enough to contain any member of the basic execution character set and [...]*". And follows it with "*Every byte has a unique address.*".

Comment: There are also machines which cannot address bytes, only words. The compiler has to simulate byte addressing.

Comment: Well, sizeof(char) is defined as 1, incrementing a char pointer increases its value by 1, and ptrdiff_t is an integer type. This implies that with regular C/C++ pointers characters are the "units" of memory, the smallest addressable entity.

Comment: @RaymondChen it doesn't have to: it could simply define `CHAR_BIT` to be the size of word.

Comment: @Ruslan yet there is quite a history of 9 bit chars on 18/36 bit word-addressed systems...

Comment: You got it completely backwards. Byte is defined to be the smallest addressable unit, whatever that it is. Actually designer of the compiler sometimes have to choose: 1) make 8 bit the smallest addressable unit, sometimes this means software emulation because hardware doesn't support it, 2) use non-8-bit byte, sometimes this means awkward and non-conventional ABI, e.g. 16 bit char 3) use 8-bit byte but not fully addressable, making it non C compliant, e.g. char is aligned to even addresses.

Comment: Erm. Is a single bit (in a bitfield, in a structure) less "addressable" than a `char` in the same structure?

Comment: @Brendan Bit fields are not addressable at all. You cannot take a pointer to them.

Comment: @walnut: Then we're defining "addressable" as "able to take a pointer from it (e.g. with `&`)"?

Comment: @Brendan No, the second sentence was only meant as further clarification, I could have left it out. There are two ways in which we could take "*addressable*": In the sense as defined and used by the standards (or a language extension) on the abstract machine, or in the sense of how the concrete architecture/CPU allows to address its memory in instructions. The question seems to conflate these two. The standards don't have any notion of "*address*" for a bit field, so they are not addressable and pointers to them make no sense.

Comment: @Ruslan True, but that would have made it incompatible with a lot of code, including the platform's own native character representation.

Comment: since the question is about the C++ standard, why is the 'c' tag being used?  C and C++ are two different languages (and getting more different with each new release of the languges

Comment: @user3629249: Actually, the languages are getting more alike each other again, with every new revision. The only thing that changed is that C is following C++, when historically C++ would follow C. This is particularly true with respect to the memory model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Thank you everyone who commented and answered, every word helps)*

Memory model of a programming language and memory model of the target machine are different things.

Yes, byte is the minimum addressable unit in context of memory model of programming language.

No, byte is not the minimum addressable unit in context of memory model of machine. For example, there are machines where minimum addressable unit is longer or shorter than the "byte" of programming language:

- longer: [HP Saturn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_Saturn)   - 4-bit unit vs 8-bit byte [gcc](http://hp48xgcc.sourceforge.net/hp48xgcc.htm) (thanks Nate).
- shorter: [IBM 360](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/36-bit_computing)    - 36-bit unit vs 6-bit byte (thanks Antti)
- longer: [Intel 8051](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_MCS-51)  - 1-bit unit vs 8-bit byte (thanks Busybee)
- longer: [Ti TMS34010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TMS34010) - 1-bit unit vs 8-bit byte (thanks Wcochran)

Answer (score 9):

A byte is the smallest addressable unit in strictly conforming C code. Whether the machine on which the C implementation executes a program supports addressing smaller units is irrelevant to this; the C implementation must present a view in which bytes are the smallest addressable unit in strictly conforming C code.

A C implementation may support addressing smaller units as an extension, such as simply by defining the results of certain pointer operations that are otherwise undefined by the C standard.

Comment: Answers to language-lawyer tagged questions are expected to refer to spec, no?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: History shows the tag was not originally on the question and was added (and not by OP) three minutes after this answer was submitted. I may update later. Or we could fix it by removing the tag, since changing questions in ways that invalidate existing answers is inappropriate.

Comment: _History shows the tag was not originally on the question_ Ok, sry then.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: I looked at this a bit, and I do not think there is much call to cite the standard here. C 2018 6.2.6.1 2 tells us that all objects are composed of bytes, except bit-fields, which we are later told are put in a “storage unit,” which is not defined. But that is well known, and other references to bytes and addressing are sprinkled through the standard and are also well known. Nothing in the standard gives a hint of sub-byte addressing, so any support for it would be an implementation extension, justifying my statement that bytes are the smallest addressable unit in strictly…

Comment: … conforming code. As a mathematician, I can appreciate a truly formal proof at times, so I might be inclined to write something more up if OP had requested it. But since a third party added the language-lawyer tag later, I am going to leave it alone for now.

Answer (score 3):

One example of a real machine and its compiler where the minimal addressable unit is smaller than a byte is the 8051 family. One compiler I was used to is Keil C51.

The minimal addressable unit is a bit. You can define a variable of this type, you can read and write it. However, the syntax to define the variable is non-standard. Of course, C51 needs several extensions to support all of this. BTW, pointers to bits are *not* allowed.

For example:

```
unsigned char bdata bitsAdressable;
sbit bitAddressed = bitsAdressable^5;

void f(void) {
    bitAddressed = 1;
}

bit singleBit;

void g(bit value) {
    singleBit = value;
}
```

Comment: From reading the Wikipedia article it seems that only part of its memory is bit-addressable, which I assume is why you need a distinct type to use it?

Comment: The type `sbit` is needed to allow the special definition. Actually you can define a bit variable directly as I show in the edited answer. The linker places this variable in the bit-addressable part of the internal RAM. However, the type needed is `bit`, which is also distinct.

Answer (score 2):

> Both definitions does not say that "byte" is the minimum addressable unit.

That's because they don't need to. Byte-wise types (`char`, `unsigned char`, `std::byte`, etc) have sufficient restrictions that enforce this requirement.

The size of byte-wise types is [explicitly defined to be precisely 1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.sizeof#1):

> sizeof(char), sizeof(signed char) and sizeof(unsigned char) are 1.

The alignment of byte-wise types [is the smallest alignment possible](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.align#6):

> Furthermore, the narrow character types (6.9.1) shall have the weakest alignment requirement

This doesn't have to be an alignment of 1, of course. Except... it does.

See, if the alignment were higher than 1, that would mean that a simple byte array wouldn't work. Array indexing is based on pointer arithmetic, and pointer arithmetic determines the next address based on `sizeof(T)`. But if `alignof(T)` is greater than `sizeof(T)`, then the second element in any array of `T` would be misaligned. That's not allowed.

So even though the standard doesn't explicitly say that the alignment of bytewise types is 1, other requirements ensure that it must be.

Overall, this means that every pointer to an object has an alignment at least as restrictive as a byte-wise type. So no object pointer can be misaligned, relative to the alignment of byte-wise types. All valid, non-NULL pointers (pointers to a live object or to a past-the-end pointer) must therefore be at least aligned enough to point to a `char`.

Similarly, the difference between two pointers is [defined in C++](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.add#5) as the difference between the array indices of the elements pointed to by those pointers (pointer arithmetic in C++ requires that the two pointers point into the same array). Additive pointer arithmetic is as previously stated based on the `sizeof` the type being pointed to.

Given all of these facts, even if an implementation has pointers whose addresses can address values smaller than `char`, it is functionally *impossible* for the C++ abstract model to generate a pointer and still have that pointer count as valid (pointing to an object/function, a past-the-end of an array, or be NULL). You could create such a pointer value with a cast from an integer. But you would be creating an invalid pointer value.

So while technically there could be smaller addresses on the machine, you could never actually use them in a valid, well-formed C++ program.

Obviously compiler extensions could do anything. But as far as conforming programs are concerned, it simply isn't possible to generate valid pointers that are misaligned for byte-wise types.

Answer (score 1):

I programmed both the [TMS34010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TMS34010) and its successor TMS34020 graphics chips back in the early 1990's and they had a flat address space and were *bit* addressable i.e. addresses indexed each bit. This was very useful for computer graphics of the time and back when memory was a lot more precious.

The [embedded C-compiler](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/components/ti/TMS340xx/TMS34010_C_Compiler_Reference_Guide_1988.pdf) didn't really have away to access individual bits directly, since from a (standard) C language point of view the byte was still the smallest unit as pointed out in a previous post.

Thus if you want to read/write a stream of bits in C, you need to read/write (at least) a byte at a time and buffer (for example when writing a Arithmetic or Huffman Coder).